# Looking to Animate a grids margin with a selected tab event, WITHOUT using Blend

Tags: c#, wpf, blend

I have a project that will have multiple tabs. When the user selects a tab, I would like the grid that's inside that tab to slide out. I figure I can accomplish that by changing the grids margin. I actually have a solution that works, but it requires 2 DLL's from Blend to be included. I would think the same effect is possible without using Blend but I can't figure it out. Below is the storyboard and tabItems xaml

```
    <Storyboard x:Key="tabAdminSlide">
        <ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Margin)" Storyboard.TargetName="grid1">
            <EasingThicknessKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="400,0,0,0"/>
            <EasingThicknessKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="0,0,0,0">
                <EasingThicknessKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                    <ExponentialEase EasingMode="EaseOut"/>
                </EasingThicknessKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
            </EasingThicknessKeyFrame>
        </ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>

    <TabItem Header="Run as Admin" x:Name="tabAdmin" Background="LightBlue">
         <i:Interaction.Triggers>
             <ei:DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedIndex, ElementName=tabControl}" Value="0">
                 <ei:ControlStoryboardAction Storyboard="{StaticResource tabAdminSlide}"/>
             </ei:DataTrigger>
         </i:Interaction.Triggers> 
            <Grid Height="Auto" x:Name="grid1" Width="Auto">
                <Grid.Background>
                    <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="-0.002,0.498" EndPoint="1.084,0.498">
                        <GradientStop Color="LightBlue" Offset="0.446" />
                        <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1" />
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Grid.Background>
                <Button Content="Button" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="40,179,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
            </Grid>
    </TabItem>
```

It looks like

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <ei:DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedIndex, ElementName=tabControl}" Value="0">
        <ei:ControlStoryboardAction Storyboard="{StaticResource tabAdminSlide}"/>
    </ei:DataTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Is the part I need to replace but I can't be sure. Any help would be appriciated

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use

```
<TabItem.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Selector.Selected">
        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource tabAdminSlide}" />
    </EventTrigger>
</TabItem.Triggers>
```

instead of

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>  
    <ei:DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedIndex, ElementName=tabControl}" Value="0">  
        <ei:ControlStoryboardAction Storyboard="{StaticResource tabAdminSlide}"/>  
    </ei:DataTrigger>  
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```